# Take input from node call nodejs

Tags: node.js, console, console-application

Just wondering, how do you take input directly from the node call? I know you can do it in Python. Here is an example of what I want to achive: 
**Code:**

```js
function main(x,y) {
 return x * y;
}
```

**Command Call:**

```
node index.js 2 2
```

Or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `process.argv`

```
let inputArr=process.argv.slice(2);
console.log(inputArr) // [2,2]
```

we are skipping the first two element of the array `process.argv` because the first two elements will be always - node and the path to your script

Comment: Both are good, but I marked this answer because it added an easy example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `process.argv` this will return an array containing the arguments you passed in CLI

Ref: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/